# Publishing an add-in for recent desktops only

Tags: office-js

The add-in we are planning to publish through AppSource will only be used by users with recent Windows/Mac/web versions of Office. (The add-in helps lawyers to retrieve clauses previously stored by them in our SaaS application.)

I noticed the warning that publication on AppSource will involve tests for combinations of platform and Office desktop versions that use Internet Explorer. However, supporting Internet Explorer would be enormously costly for us, and we know with certainty that none of our users will actually be using the add-in with Internet Explorer.

Is there any possibility to publish an add-in on AppSource targeting only recent desktops/web versions of Office? We have no problem to:

- explicitly state in the AppSource publication state that support for old versions of Office is excluded, or even explicitly limit the potential audience to recent versions of O365 subscribers
- include a check in the add-in that would alert users about their use of Internet Explorer

Anything would be helpful here, as Internet Explorer support is really a show stopper for us.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to publish an add-in for a subset of browsers. I think you may check out the web browser platform at runtime and let users know that it is not fully supported. That's the best way to handle such cases. But I am not sure whether such add-ins will be approved. In theory, all the functionality should be the same.

The [Design guidelines for Office, Outlook, and Outlook Mobile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/marketplace/certification-policies#design-guidelines-for-office-outlook-and-outlook-mobile) section states the following:

> Add-ins must be compatible with all versions of Internet Explorer 11 and later, and the latest versions of Microsoft Edge, Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, and Apple Safari (macOS).

Comment: But on AppSource, I see many plugins listing only a subset (e.g., Grammarly only supports Word on Mac & Word on Web). How is this achieved?

Comment: In your case you are not interested in supported OS or applications. Web browsers are clearly defined in the requirements for the AppSource. When you see the `Word on the web` item as a supported platforms, that means all browsers are supported.